# How to store the result of hive to a text file in local in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, hive, text-files

I want to query distinct dates from the date column in the hive and store the same to a text file in local.

```
hive  -e "SELECT distinct(part_date) AS distinct_date FROM ${table_name} where partition_date between ${start_date} and ${end_date}"; >> local/path/staging_temp.txt
```

This is giving me an empty file instead of the distinct dates. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you would remove the semicolon it would work. By adding a semicolon the redirection (>>) and hive command are separate bash commands. Plus, I would redirect the output stream by > and 2>&1 will redirect error stream to where the output stream is getting redirected i.e.

```
hive  -e "SELECT distinct(part_date) AS distinct_date FROM ${table_name} where partition_date between ${start_date} and ${end_date}" > local/path /staging_temp.txt 2>&1
```